# Laptop screen dims after 20 seconds, cannot change that

Tags: fedora, laptop, brightness

On my HP laptop with Fedora 23, screen dims after 20 seconds when using batteries, and I couldn't find a way to change that. I've set

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

This is annoying and forces me to keep the laptop connected to the power plug at all times.

Is there a way to increase the delay or to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to the latest kernel version (4.3.3-303) the problem disappeared.  Apparently the `gsettings` command above is now taking effect.